# python http.request autentification cookie web login

Tags: python, http, cookies, request

i have this small funnction :

```
def wp_login_check(url,username,password):
    UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"
    headers = { 'User-Agent': UA, 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cookie': 'wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check' }
    http = httplib2.Http(timeout=10, disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
    http.follow_redirects = True
    body = { 'log':username,'pwd':password,'wp-submit':'Login','testcookie':'1' }

    response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(body))


    url2 = url.replace('/wp-login.php','/wp-admin/plugin-install.php')
    response1, content1 = http.request(url2)
    print content1
```

i need use cookies of the first request to second request .. how can make this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to use httplib2**

Grab the cookie from the response header `Set-cookie` and include it in subsequent requests:

```
def wp_login_check(url,username,password):
    UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"
    headers = { 'User-Agent': UA, 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cookie': 'wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check' }
    http = httplib2.Http(timeout=10, disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
    http.follow_redirects = True
    body = { 'log':username,'pwd':password,'wp-submit':'Login','testcookie':'1' }

    response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(body))

    # Grab the cookie for later presentation
    headers = {'Cookie': response['set-cookie']}

    url2 = url.replace('/wp-login.php','/wp-admin/plugin-install.php')
    response1, content1 = http.request(url2, headers=headers)
    print content1
```

---

**Alternative**

If you can, use a [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) module session instead of `httplib2`:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
resp1 = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
resp2 = s.post(...)
```

You will find that the cookie will be persisted in the session and then presented to the server on subsequent requests.

You will also find `requests` to be a much more pleasant module to work with.

Comment: @kingcope : answer for httplib2

Comment: {'status': '400', 'content-length': '292', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'Apache', 'connection': 'close', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Fri, 19 Dec 2014 17:56:22 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'} <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at easyup-shoes.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>